# unity3d - Change Image.fillAmount

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, fill

I have an image acting as a health bar, and i want to give it a cistume value more than 1:

```
    public Image healthBar;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        float health = 4;

        healthBar.fillAmount = health;
        Debug.Log (gameObject + ""+ healthBar.fillAmount);
    }
```

Problem is no matter what value I give health, the fillAmount always goes back to 1. Is there any way to make it higher ?

Comment: FillAmount represents a value between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%), which means you need to work with fractions. If you calculate your health as currentHealth/Maxhealth you'll get something that will work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29410750/1016885) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fillAmount is a value of 0-1, with at 1 the full image being shown. There is no behavior yet for numbers over 1.

You could change the width of the image based on the maximum health and calculate the percentage that needs to be filled.

```
   healthBar.rectTransform.rect.width = maxHealth * healthBarWidth;
   healthBar.fillAmount = health / maxHealth;
```

If you don't want one bar, but multiple images like hearts that still are filled partially, you might be able to do it with a tiled image which automatically truncates at the edges.

Comment: Thank you, but why don't they allow us to just change it to whatever we want? the way I am going to do it now is by changing the enemies damage to be very small numbers.

Comment: It's because the fill options aren't really made for that, there are also cases where there isn't really an obvious behavior, like the radial fill for example. Also almost every game with health bars works with percentages and fills it based on the current and max health. Never really using the health var directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a spelling error when creating the heath float. You call health when you declared "healt"

Comment: Actually no, this must have happened when i posted the code here, no errors in Mono. I will edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 healthBar.fillAmount += health;
```

Try to do the increment in the `fillAmount` value, as it will assign the value you want it, and then change the code little bit in order to reach the exact number.